# How to give write permission to var/log folder to log errors

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging, error-logging

I am using python logging in django and I want to log errors to var/log folder. I am getting this error :

```
Unable to configure handler 'exception_logs': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/exceptions.log'
```

Below is my code snippet in `settings.py`

```
'handlers': {'exception_logs': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'filename': '/var/log/exceptions.log',
    },
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make sure the file has been created

```
sudo touch /var/log/exceptions.log
```

Then change the ownership of the file to the user that the server runs as. Assuming this is `www-data`:

```
sudo chown www-data /var/log/exceptions.log
```

Alternatively, you could change the group owner of the file, and add the user to that group.

Comment: I've tried this with wordpress for example and doing this does not matter. The custom PHP application log files in /var/log/httpd/ folder are not being written.