# How can a PHP application log errors to a custom file in the: /var/log/httpd/ directory?

Tags: php, logging

I am attempting to have a specific PHP script/application output to the following log file on CentOS7:

```
/var/log/httpd/custom_error.log
```

I have looked for different solutions with regard to this, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758523/how-to-give-write-permission-to-var-log-folder-to-log-errors) is the only closest answer I've seen, but still was unsuccessful.

Since I have multiple PHP frameworks/applications running (WordPress, Drupal, etc), I am using PHP's script-based override, and each script process uses its own override respectively. For example, the following does not work:

```
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/httpd/wp_error.log' );
```

The ownership and permissions on that wp_error.log file are set to apache:apache 644.

In contrast, this works successfully when I have the following:

```
ini_set('error_log', '/var/www/wordpress/wp_error.log' );
```

Or:

```
ini_set('error_log', '/var/www/drupal/dru_error.log' );
```

Comment: Would you care to tell us _how_ you tried to achieve that?

Comment: There is a configuration setting for php: `error_log`. I suggest you modify that?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the `php.ini` in there is a directive called `error_log =`

Comment: apache:apache 644 only works if your apache is running under the account  of apache. Is that the account it is running under?

Comment: @arkascha Updated my post with more info.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using the CentOS default process ownership for the httpd server, so yes, Apache is running under the user:group of apache:apache. 644 should thus be working. FWIW, there are no SELinux ACLs on these folders either.

Comment: If those different cases really come from the same system, then obviously you miss something. Tripple check file paths, names, permissions, _especially_ the permissions of all folders up from the file system root to the log file. Then, when you did, sit down and _really_ check all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my problem I needed to change the ownership of the parent httpd folder in the path /var/log/**httpd**/ to apache:apache user/group:

```
sudo touch /var/log/httpd/custom.log
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/log/httpd
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my research leads me to believe that Apache outputs its related logs to the syslog which is owned by root, which in turn writes logs to that folder.

However, if I change the ownership to Apache, root can still write to those log files, but now Apache and its related processes (e.g., PHP) can directly write to that log folder as well.